# Tips for getting rid of SYNC instructions?

Tags: spacechem

In most of my solutions I have this motif:

```
          |
          v
(red)  : Sync -> Start -> Sync  ->
(blue) : Sync -> Sync  -> Start ->
          ^
          |
```

just to make sure that the blue Waldo runs first.

Except in the early research levels where counting steps is an option, I've always had to do something like this, up to 6 SYNCs at one point, which was not very pleasing!

What are more elegant options for synchronizing the Waldos?

Comment: Why would you want the blue Waldo to always run first? I as I understand it (very new) when two Waldos hit a command at the same time, the red always fires first.  So why not just build your solution so red should run first?  it would seem to be easier?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On research levels where inputs execute instantly (it's not waiting for the pipeline, etc), you can usually eliminate all SYNC instructions by just making the path length for the blue and red Waldos equal.  One instance where you can't do this is if you perform a single rotation (or generally an odd imbalance of rotations), as the path length for a circuit will always be even, and rotations add one cycle.

If you just want your blue Waldo to just run opposite the red, you could just move the start much earlier in the circuit, for instance like in this puzzle (final one on the first planet)

[image]

Eliminating SYNC instructions can be much more difficult when you have reactors that run much faster than the input can keep up however.  If you can tolerate some imbalance in input times and the reactants come at a roughly predictable ratio, you can sometimes avoid it by just spacing them out.